# How to display file size in the mode line

Tags: mode-line

How can I display file size in MB or KB in the mode line? I have the icon for  encoding setting, title of the buffer, etc but have no file size in there.

Comment: How to you customize your mode-line? Make it clear so that user can know how to add code to your custom mode-line.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, just run `M-x size-indication-mode`. See section 14.18 of the Emacs manual for other things you can do.

Answer (score 1):

Or use mode-line-format `%-constructs` (`%I`).